# In Azure DevOps, is there any way to quickly apply a pull request or changeset to a different git repo?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have two git repos that are forks of the same codebase, and I created a pull request against one of them (let's call it repo X) and squash-merged the changes into it. I'd like to apply the same changes to the other repo (let's call it repo P). Is there any way to do this quickly without manually copying and pasting changes? Even a way to export and reimport a diff would be OK; I don't want to go copying changes because there are several files that changed and that seems rather error prone!

Answer (score 2):

Azure DevOps supports forking as a first class citizen now, much like github.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio

It allows you to do PRs across git repos that originated from the same place.

[image: pull request via forks]

Although you may already know that.

I haven't tried but I would anticipate you could do a PR from a fork to the upstream repo, then ensuring you do not delete the source branch; do another PR. Hmmm although could it be *between* forks... I'm not sure... if that doesn't work then "pure git" will be your answer without aid in Azure DevOps directly.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I have seen that feature, but it doesn't seem like this will work for me right now because the branch was already squash merged and deleted, and I don't want to bring in all changes from that fork, just the one change that I made in that pull request.

Comment: No worries, if you find a clean approach please do share it as it sounds like an interesting problem.

Comment: Maybe I could cherry-pick the squashed commit into a new branch, then merge that branch? But I'm not sure what to base that branch off of...the two forks have certain differences that I'm not entirely aware of!

Answer (score 0):

Just with git, you can simply pull the latest commits from the source repo, switch the remote and push to your desired branch.

Assuming they have the same codebase, this will bring in the new commits very cleanly. However, it may not be terribly obvious this has occurred from the Azure UI.

Show remotes

```sh
git remote -v
```

Set a new remote

```sh
git remote set-url origin git@whatever.git
```

Comment: Hmm, how would I do this when the commits have already been squash-merged and the branch was deleted? I'm thinking I might need to cherry-pick but I'm not too familiar with how that works or if that would actually be appropriate here...

Comment: As the history is the same, the new commit or commits should apply cleanly.. if the history is not the same, something is probably wrong.

If your fork has independent changes, this may not work directly, though you could create an intermediate branch and pull the changes there.

Do try it with a test repository!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a branch based on the commit node you want to merge to repo P. Then create a pr to merge this branch into repo P .Just like the cherry-pick method you think of. But the flaw in this approach is that you can't specify one change to merge. The commit node that creates the branch will contain the previous changes.

In addition, the two forks have certain differences that you are not exactly aware of, which is also likely to cause a merger conflict.

[image]
[image]